# Find a constant $C_d$ to bound an inequality between a norm and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inequality

> Define
>
> $$\|{p}\| := \max\{ |p(x)| \mid x \in [10,100]\}$$
>
> where
>
> $$p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^da_ix^i$$
>
> $$\langle p, q \rangle = \int_0^1 p(x) q(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$
>
> Prove that there is a constant $C_d$ such that that $\|p\|^2 \leq C_d \langle p, p \rangle$.

How to find the relationship between a norm and an inner product?

Answer (score 1):

The question is about equivalence of norms, here one being the sup over $[10,100]$, the other being derived from the scalar product. The space of degree $d$ polynomials $E_d={\Bbb R}[x]$ is (finite) $(d+1)$-dimensional. Any two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.

Without giving any explicit bounds we may show that 
 $\lim_{d\rightarrow \infty} C_d=+\infty$.

To see this assume the contrary and that $C_d\leq M<+\infty$ for all $d$.
Let $f:[0,100]\rightarrow {\Bbb R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)=0$ for all $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $f(10)=1$. By Weierstrass we may find a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ so that $\sup_{0\leq x\leq 100}|P_n(x)-f(x)|$ goes to zero with $n$. But then 
$$ 1=f(10)^2 \leq \liminf_n\|P_n\|^2 \leq M \langle P_n,P_n\rangle=  M \langle P_n-f,P_n-f\rangle \rightarrow 0$$
is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes I know the equivalence between any two norms in finite dimentional space. But the difficult point in this problem is to find a such constant $C_d$ related to the order of polynomial $p$

Comment: @Gatsby Ok, so you need an explicit estimate in terms of the given data?

Comment: Actually I want to get sth like $C_d=f(d)$. Because the second part of this problem that I did't post is to solve $\lim\limits_{d\to\infty} C_d$...

Comment: Depends a bit then, because it is easy to see that $\lim_d C_d=+\infty$ without having to give an explicit bound. If you wish I can add that to the post. It is much harder to actually get explicit upper/lower bounds.

Comment: Yeah, so can you do that?